# How to input all 50 states in the United States without having to type them all in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am trying to delete the rows in my dataset that has a U.S state name. I hope there is a way to input into the code without typing all 50 of them.
Below I am sharing the big picture and where I would like to have these states input.

```
cshealthpredictors %>% 
 filter(!region %in% c("Alabama", "Arkansas" ,"Missouri","Texas","Georgia"))
```

Comment: Use the built in `state.name`.

Comment: As a general rule though, if you have a large list of values to use, I'd be sourcing that list of values from a known source (e.g. google found this one - https://github.com/jasonong/List-of-US-States/blob/master/states.csv ) and using an `inner_join` to subset your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ritchie mentions in the comments there's a built in for that in base R.

```r
state.name
#>  [1] "Alabama"        "Alaska"         "Arizona"        "Arkansas"      
#>  [5] "California"     "Colorado"       "Connecticut"    "Delaware"      
#>  [9] "Florida"        "Georgia"        "Hawaii"         "Idaho"         
#> [13] "Illinois"       "Indiana"        "Iowa"           "Kansas"        
#> [17] "Kentucky"       "Louisiana"      "Maine"          "Maryland"      
#> [21] "Massachusetts"  "Michigan"       "Minnesota"      "Mississippi"   
#> [25] "Missouri"       "Montana"        "Nebraska"       "Nevada"        
#> [29] "New Hampshire"  "New Jersey"     "New Mexico"     "New York"      
#> [33] "North Carolina" "North Dakota"   "Ohio"           "Oklahoma"      
#> [37] "Oregon"         "Pennsylvania"   "Rhode Island"   "South Carolina"
#> [41] "South Dakota"   "Tennessee"      "Texas"          "Utah"          
#> [45] "Vermont"        "Virginia"       "Washington"     "West Virginia" 
#> [49] "Wisconsin"      "Wyoming"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>